# Twitter Bootstrap: Remove/Toggle the active state of checkbox-like button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

With twitters Bootstrap I've created a button group with radiobox behaviour to let the user choose between the different states. This works out of the box as supposed.

I arranged a jsFiddle with the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpxWj/

What I tried (and want) is that the pressed state can be removed when I click the active button second time.

I tried with jQuerys `removeClass()` to remove the `active` class from the `btn` classes but it won't work. *(I also tried removing with `.on()` but this just keeps the active always hidden/removed)*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/Luuk/jpxWj/1/), quite an unknown event phenomenon, in my opinion. You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/).

**Edit:**

To ellaborate, the reason why a simple `.removeClass` doesn't work, is because there are multiple listeners, listening to the same event. So when the `click` event is fired, a normal `.removeClass` would remove the class, but then the Twitter Bootstrap handler would add it again! To prevent any other handlers from being executed after yours, you can do `e.stopPropagation`. However, this does not stop the handlers attached to the same element as yours, it only stops the ones further up the tree. To completely make sure no other handlers are executed after yours, you can use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/).

Comment: This is just great - thank you very much! I did try with `event.preventDefault()` but it didn't work. `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` works as expected. I updated the jsFiddle to narrow the scope a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/jpxWj/2/

Thanks again for the hint and the help!

Comment: No problem, I added some clarification, thought it might help.

Comment: Hey, it doesn't work - could be that it doesn't work in bootstrap 3?

Comment: @Dejell, I had to combine `e.preventDefault();` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` to get it to work properly in bootstrap 3 as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 Update:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-group .btn.active',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       $(this).find('input').removeAttr('checked');
       $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: Adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` worked for me.