# How can a bootstrap radio button group be reset?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap radio button group in a toolbar and I would love for the buttons to be reset if clicked again. So far I've tried it with this http://jsfiddle.net/a6xZt/ but unfortunately it is not working.

Although I can remove any other class, I can't remove the `active` class. Or is there a way to reset the entire group? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582757/twitter-bootstrap-remove-toggle-the-active-state-of-checkbox-like-button-group

Comment: Awesome! This is it. I did not find it before. Need to increase my stack overflow search skill ;-). Thank you sir!

Comment: I am not sure if it works in bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical mark_selector" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
```

to

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical mark_selector" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
```

edit:

misread question: if radio functionality is mandatory, try to

$().button('toggle')

as bootstrap doc says (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons)

cheers

Comment: Tried this before and did not work. The link above works, though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with spoutnik, you'll need to change the data-toggle to "buttons-checkbox".

The default radio button functionality doesn't allow it to be "un-clicked".

The only problem with this solution is that you are allowing users to select more than one option with the default use of a checkbox.

Here is the code you would need for the checkbox:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical mark_selector" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
```

There is a way to change the way the checkboxes work the way you want them though, ill try and figure it out real quick for you.