# Deselect bootstrap 3 radio button on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to allow deselect a bootstrap btn-group radio button without an extra button.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582757/twitter-bootstrap-remove-toggle-the-active-state-of-checkbox-like-button-group) answer, I wrote [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deligeli/gqf23tmw/) but it doesn't work for me. Why?
I see by looking at the log that the method is being called on second time click.

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn.active', function(e){
    console.log("test");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $('input:radio[name="options"]').parent().removeClass("active");
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked/>Radio 1 (preselected)
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">Radio 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off">Radio 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqf23tmw/7/). For some reason you have to call both stopPropagate and preventDefault to make it work.

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn.active', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this, $('input:radio[name="options"]', this));
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('input:radio[name="options"]', this).prop('checked', false);
})
```

Comment: weird. can you explain it?

Comment: e.stopImmediatePropagation() prevents bootstrap click event from executing and e.preventDefault() prevents radio button from being checked. Apparently checking radio button causes event bubbling and the bootstrap click event is executed.