# jQuery removeClass() sometime works, but sometimes it doesn't

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand jQuery a bit more. I am trying to clear the class 'active' from a checkbox. There are two checkboxes in button group. See code below:

```
<!--    MAIN BODY       -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div id="" class="btn-group" role="group" >
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary active" id = "clear" >
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbclear" name="tool_option_myCanvas" data-tool="clear" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="title"> 
                    <span class="fa fa-undo"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary" id = "btn2" >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="tool_option_myCanvas" data-tool="fg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="title"> 
                    <span class="fa fa-eraser"></span>
                </label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

(function($) {

    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $("#clear").removeClass("active");
    });
    $('#clear').click(function() {
        $("#clear").removeClass("active");
}); 
})(jQuery);
```

If I click on btn2, it will remove the class, 'active', and work as expected. If I click on clear, nothing happens.

Another thing I tried is, when i replace my click handler for 'clear' with this:

```
    $('#clear').click(function() {
        $("#clear").removeClass("btn-primary active");
});
```

The class, 'btn-primary active' is removed. So why can't I remove the active class alont when I click on the 'clear' button? My end goal is to have the 'active' class removed when I click on the 'active' button.

Comment: Clicking on clear button also removes active class as expected! https://jsfiddle.net/auomkhsm/ If you click on `Clear` after clicking `btn2` then of course nothing will happen as `active` class would already have been removed.,

Comment: stil not seeing it

Answer (score 0):

I used this: [Twitter Bootstrap: Remove/Toggle the active state of checkbox-like button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582757/twitter-bootstrap-remove-toggle-the-active-state-of-checkbox-like-button-group)

```
    $('#clear').click(function(event) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $("#clear").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I've been having a similar problem for days now and event.stopImmediatePropgation() fixed it. Why? 

I was having an error with jquery discarding my .removeClass calls; they were working until it made its way through the jquery code.